# Can I create a map in which some of the keys have no values or are null?

Tags: kotlin

I want to have a map where some values are blank so that when I loop through the map and run a function I can take advantage of default parameters:

```
fun main() {
    val users = mapOf("user_one@gmail.com" to null, "user_two@gmail.com" to "Windows", "user_three@gmail.com" to "macOS")

    for (item in users) {
        println(displayAlertMessage(item.value, item.key))
    }
}

fun displayAlertMessage(os: String = "Unknown OS", email: String): String {
    return "There's a new sign-in request on $os for your Google Account $email."
}
```

I understand there's something weird about using null and it expecting a string, but if I just use `""` as the value for the first pair then the function doesn't use the default parameter. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your existing code apply the default value for parameter `os`, you'll have to invoke it without `os` parameter:

```
fun main() {
    val users = mapOf("user_one@gmail.com" to null, "user_two@gmail.com" to "Windows", "user_three@gmail.com" to "macOS")

    for (item in users) {
        if (item.value == null)
            println(displayAlertMessage(email = item.key))
        else
            println(displayAlertMessage(item.value!!, item.key))
    }
}
```

I would probably have done something like this (less code) if only one occurrence of call to `displayAlertMessage`:

```
for (item in users) {
    println(displayAlertMessage(item.value ?: "Unknown OS", item.key))
}
```

Then you can remove default value from `displayAlertMessage` like this:

```
fun displayAlertMessage(os: String, email: String): String {
    return "There's a new sign-in request on $os for your Google Account $email."
}
```